# Надпись все время висит

Tags: php

Вот эта надпись 'неправильный email' висит над окном "кому", а должна высвечиватся только тогда, когда некорректно пишут email и исчезать по обновлению страницы или написанию правильного email.

```
 <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
    if ($_POST['submit'])
     {

      $to      = $_POST['to'];

      $subject = $_POST['subj'];
      $message = $_POST['msg'];
      $file= $_POST['file'];
      // Заголовки сообщения, в них определяется кодировка сообщения, поля From, To и т.д.
      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
      $headers .= "To: $to\r\n";
      $headers .= "From: гыгы <мое мыло>";
    //  mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location: mail.php");
     }
      require_once "smtpauth.php";
      MailSmtp ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])) {
    echo 'не правильный email';

    }

    ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <pre>
        кому:   <input type="text" name="to">
        тема: <input type="text" name="subj">
        письмо <textarea rows="10" cols="20" type="text" name="msg"></textarea>
        <p>
            <label for="text">отправить файл:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send mail!" name="submit">
      </pre>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Весит надпись потому что не умеем пользоваться конструкциями **if () then {}**

```
 header("Location: mail.php");
     }
```

Тут закрывается проверка на POST вот и висит эта надпись.
Из того что есть примерно так вот будет выглядеть. , но не айс код.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit']) AND $check==0)
         {
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])){
          echo 'не правильный email';
       // выход какой-то из проверки сделать
$check=0;

         }
else{
         $to= $_POST['to'];
         $subject = $_POST['subj'];
         $message = $_POST['msg'];
         $file= $_POST['file'];
          $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
          $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
          $headers .= "To: $to\r\n";
          $headers .= "From: гыгы <мое мыло>";
          require_once "smtpauth.php";
          MailSmtp ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
          header("Location: mail.php"); 
          $check=1;
}
         } 
  else
{echo "Форма отправлялась ранее";}
```

*Но если честно код написан не очень хорошо, по этому советую его переписать.*

Comment: в первом варианте никакой реакции на некорректный email

Comment: [поиск][1] это уже решенный вопрос ранее.
[1]: http://hashcode.ru/search/?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B&t=question

Comment: вот честно не нужно лентяйничать! почитай посмотри, возьми листок бумаги и по шагам распиши что должно за чем идти какие проверки на каком этапе. Не ленись, сделай раз и поймешь что такое логика!

Comment: Неужели так сложно придумать решение. Обновил ответ.

Это лентяйство. А логика тут прямая. Не хочу делать пусть за меня напишут.

Я думаю за следующие подобные вопросы будут только минусы в профиль. (тут лентяев так учат :) )

либо переменная либо куку поставь пользователю.

Comment: во первых ничего я не обновлял, разве что нажал F5 на этой странице кто его знает какая здесь особенност сайта и прочее, причем здесь леньтяйство? я продемонстрировал готовый ксрипт который работает не совсем корректно, я уже который день искал подобные решение, и обратился до тех кто знает больше это по вашему лентяйство??

Comment: обязательно приму, а об каком ответе идется речь?)

Comment: об этом ответе, у него слева есть такая галочка. на неё жмякаешь и ответ можно принять.

Comment: сделал в лучшем виде)

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на корректность не там находиться, почту нужно проверять только тогда когда нажата кнопка отправить.

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
if ($_POST['submit'])
 {

  $to      = $_POST['to'];

  $subject = $_POST['subj'];
  $message = $_POST['msg'];
  $file= $_POST['file'];
  // Заголовки сообщения, в них определяется кодировка сообщения, поля From, To и т.д.
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
  $headers .= "To: $to\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: гыгы <мое мыло>";
//  mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header("Location: mail.php");

if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['to'])) {
echo 'не правильный email';

}

 }
  require_once "smtpauth.php";
  MailSmtp ($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: надпись в этом случае вообще не в каком варианте не отображается, правильно я воожу email или нет

Comment: Не работает видимо и за редиректа:

header("Location: mail.php");

удалите его, зачем он там вообще нужен ? mail.php пропишите лучше в экшене самой формы.